# Google Script Table Chart link as text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working with a google script to make my data show in a more user friendly way then just a huge spreadsheet with multiple people filtering at the same time.

Using script shown further below I was able to create : [image]

My problem is the red highlighted part. this column (the next as well) would always either be blank or show a link. Now this is an example so it is a short link which you could easily copy from there and paste to the top.

1.What I want to achieve: is to have that link clickable (redirect link in the spreadsheet) 2.Ideally I would set up in spreadsheet a word like "link" with a hyperlink like "https://www.google.de/" and you would then in the chart just click the word link and it takes you to the link.

Below I will add the script I have been using so far.

```
//Get the spreadSheet Url

var ssKey ="-Link to Spreadsheet-";

function doGet() 
{
var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Database");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssKey);

//Get the compelte data from sheet name "-Name-"

var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("OPEN").getDataRange().setNumberFormat

('@STRING@');//getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);

//To provide a category or dprodown filter

var oneFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Type of Request").build();
var secondFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Work: Business").build();  
var thirdFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Work: ").build();  
var forthFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("IDEA").build();
var fifthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("REGION / FUNCTION").build();
var sixthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("-name of filter 6-").build();  


// To get data of spreadhseet in table format
var tablechart = Charts.newTableChart()
                .setDimensions(1750,1000)
                .setOption('allowHtml',true)
                .setOption('width', '100%')
                .setOption('lenght', '100%')
                .enablePaging(10)
                .build();


// To Add Age filter and table data in dashboard
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
                .setDataTable(dataRange)
                .bind([oneFilter,secondFilter,thirdFilter,forthFilter,fifthFilter,sixthFilter],[tablechart]).build();


var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var filterPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var filterPanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  filterPanel.add(oneFilter).add(secondFilter).add(thirdFilter).setSpacing(10);
  filterPanel2.add(forthFilter).add(fifthFilter).add(sixthFilter).setSpacing(10);
  chartPanel.add(tablechart).setSpacing(10);


  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(filterPanel2).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a link from the script, you'll have to set the value of the cell as if it was a formula you are writting within the Spreadsheet. For this, we will use 'HYPERLINK(url, value)' into the cell. You can perhaps create a method that will create the string with the formula, and just set that value to the cell.

Try this approach:

```
function getHyperLink(url,val) {
  return "=HYPERLINK("+"\""+url+"\""+","+"\""+val+"\""+")";
}


//Example to obtain the value of the url and the text to set in as a link
    var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var curRow = aCell.getRow();
    var val = aSheet.getRange(curRow, 0).getValue();
    var url = aSheet.getRange(curRow, 1).getValue();
    aSheet.getRange(curRow, 2).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setValue(getHyperLink(url,val));
```

Comment: Rivero, Thank you very Much for your help however I am not sure I understand. I understand the principle function of the " gethyperlink" and also that some variable had to be defined. What I do not get : Currow which would stand for current row however would this do the job for multiple lines not just 1? Also most importantly this was first time I was working with script in a visual way so i am not really sure how to combine the code you wrote with the script I already have.